# Webpack import bootstrap .js and .css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, webpack

I am building an app using react, bootstrap and webpack using es6 with babel.

But I can't import boostrap.js and bootstrap.css to my app.

My webpack.config.js

```
    var webpack = require('webpack'),
  HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'),
  path = require('path'),
  srcPath = path.join(__dirname, 'src');

module.exports = {
  target: 'web',
  cache: true,
  entry: {
    module: path.join(srcPath, 'module.js'),
    common: ['react', 'react-router', 'alt']
  },
  resolve: {
    root: srcPath,
    extensions: ['', '.js'],
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'tmp'),
    publicPath: '',
    filename: '[name].js',
    library: ['Example', '[name]'],
    pathInfo: true
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel?cacheDirectory'}
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('common', 'common.js'),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: 'src/index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           $: "jquery",
           jQuery: "jquery"
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           bootstrap: "bootstrap.css",
    }),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],

  debug: true,
  devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './tmp',
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```

So in my .js files (react components) I am trying to do: import 'bootstrap'. But the css is not being implemented. The .js imports works well.

So how can I import boostrap or configure webpack?

Comment: I managed to get it done using the guide found [here](http://blog.theodybrothers.com/2015/07/how-to-use-bootstrap-css-only-and.html): It only helps with loading bootstrap.css but that's all I needed.

Answer (score 8):

You need to do the following things to make it work:

1. In your webpack config file, `resolve` section, make sure your bootstrap css file path is included.

As an example:

```
var bootstrapPath = path.join(
    __dirname,
    'development/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css'
);
```

Then in your webpack config object:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        jquery: path.join(__dirname, 'development/bower_components/jquery/jquery')
    },
    root: srcPath,
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.css'],
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', srcPath, commonStylePath, bootstrapPath]
}
```

2. Make sure you have style loader and css loader. E.g.
   `loaders:[{ test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }]`
3. Use it in your js file
   `require('bootstrap.min.css');`

Answer (score 0):

Just use the less plugin and declare them properly...

```
// Webpack file
{
  test: /\.less$/,
  loader: "style-loader!css-loader!less-loader"
},
// I have to add the regex .*? because some of the files are named like... fontello.woff2?952370
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)(\?.*)?$/,
  loader: 'url?limit=50000'
}

// Less file
@import '~bootstrap/less/bootstrap';
```

I am still working on the JS but I will let you know soon :-)