# Prevent WebPack from renaming Bootstrap css classnames?

Tags: webpack

I'm a webpack novice, but I can't seem to figure out how to get some resources that I previously was including in my app via references to them on a CDN in the `<head>` portion of a page to be included in the app.

Issues I have:
1) Bootstrap CSS names are being renamed. I can see that there's a local/global syntax, but that requires me editing the file. I must be doing something wrong here.

In my react App.js file, the bootstrap css file is getting added due to this:

import bootstrapStyles from '../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

2) Lots of the docs keep mentioning things like: "then you require('bootstrap.min.css')" in your react file ([Webpack import bootstrap .js and .css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686297/webpack-import-bootstrap-js-and-css)). This is supposed to happen in a React js app? Everything is import'ing in my react file. Would I just: import bootstrapStyles from 'bootstrap.min.css'

I must be missing something simple. It can't be this hard.

Comment: Not sure whether you'll able to keep importing it into your `App.js` file, but if you disable modules in `webpack.config.js`, class names won't be renamed – look onto `?modules` query parameter (`options.modules` option) in your `css-loader` configuration.