# Smartly import js lib with css in webpack

Tags: css, node.js, npm, webpack, bundle

I was tired of downloading js and css lib manually every time, then I jump into npm and webpack as I started a react project. But there are some awkwark:

1. Using `npm install` is fine, but I have to know where css/js/scss placed, they may be :

   ```
   node_modules\materialize-css\sass\materialize.scss
   node_modules\materialize-css\dist\js\materialize.min.js
   node_modules\sweetalert\dist\sweetalert.min.js
   node_modules\sweetalert\dist\sweetalert.css
   node_modules\hint.css\hint.min.css
   ...
   ```

   I still need found the correct path by myself, and add to `index.html` or import at `index.js`, like before , but it does reduce the time for searching lib's download link)
2. There are many js lib contain css file, but webpack is not so easy to add a lib with both css and js:

   Such as  [webpack-import-bootstrap-js-and-css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686297/webpack-import-bootstrap-js-and-css), have to add so much config code to make css import, why don't I just include the css at `index.html`? It just one line. However separate js,css import in different file make me feel uncomfortable too.

---

I hope there is a way like:

1. npm install --save sweetalert
2. add webpack config, something like(no need to know structure of a lib ):

   ```
   ...
   new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
     swal: "sweetalert",
     use_css: true, // false for someone need custom theme
     use_js: true
   }),
   ...
   ```

But I don't found a good way now.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide path to the .css file. This works for me:

```
import swal from 'sweetalert'
import 'sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css'
```