# What's the intended way to include npm libraries with the React Starter Kit?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, npm, react-starter-kit

I'm using the [React Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) and want to use an npm module for my css and javascript (namely bootstrap).

How do I integrate it properly? Simply installing it doesn't make it available on the server.

Comment: this may be the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686297/webpack-import-bootstrap-js-and-css

Answer (score 0):

To install bootstrap you actually need the npm package called react-bootstrap. So first run

```
npm install --save react-bootstrap
```

and then import the components in your app. To have the bootstrap's css and default theme, just include the cdn css files right into your main index.html file as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

If you want a starter kit that has all the needed packages in order to build rich real-world apps, but with minimal configuration, you can try http://redux-minimal.js.org/

By default redux-minimal comes with bootstrap, sass and a demo app to show you how code looks like. Alternatively you could just check the github code and borrow code that way and stick to your existing starter kit.